# adding HTML using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu:

```
<ul id="test-ul">
<li>test</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

How do i add the following HTML markup before the first li and after the last li:

```
 <li class="first">
      <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  />
    </li>

<li class="last">
      <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  />
    </li>
```

using jquery ?

Comment: You should use the jquery append method to $("#test-ul") to add to the end, and the jquery prepend method to $("#test-ul") to add to the beginning: http://api.jquery.com/append/ http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: I saw that apend does work but isnt it slow?

Comment: This will cause invalid markup. List elements (like `ul`) should contain **only** `li` elements inside.

Comment: ok how can i add an extra li?

Comment: @sp-1986  `$("#test-ul").append("<li />");` `$("#test-ul").prepend("<li />");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't valid syntax to add `div` in `ul` tag. But to undeerstand concept of adding html via Jquery, here you go

```
var str = '<div class="first"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  /></div><div class="last"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  /></div>';

$("#test-ul").append(str).prepend(str);​​​​​​​​
```

You can see Jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpqTp/).

Comment: @Simon got it first, but your solution is **much** more elegant! *And* it has a jsFiddle!.

Comment: I don't see it is more elegant. It does the same. At least it adds `div`s with the same class names.

Comment: On second thoughts I think this might not be quite what the OP is after. I think the OP would wants the `first` element before the `li`s and the `last` element after the `li`s

Comment: accepted because you have chuck norris as your name and the example helped me alot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add these elements before and after `li`. Any element other than `li` nested in a `ul` is invalid HTML.

You could however add the content within a new `li`, this would be valid.

```
​$(function(){
   var $li = $("<li></li>");
   $li.html("html code...");
   $("#test-ul").append($li);
   var $li2 = $("<li></li>");
   $li2.html("different html code..");
   $("#test-ul").prepend($li2); 
});​
```

[**SEE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/6yEgz/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test-ul").append("html here");    // after the last li

$("#test-ul").prepend("html here");   // before the first
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new LI for each, this would work.  Be aware if you add more divs it will cause issues.

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var newli = $(this).html().wrap('<li></li>');
    $('#test-ul').append(newli);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = '<li<img src="/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  /></li>';
var last = '<li><img src="/sosmck.jpg" width="27" height="15"  /></li>';

var myItems = $("li");
myItems.prepend(first);
myItems.append(last);
```